# Data is adjacent to headers in csv

Tags: python, csv

how can I put my first row of data in the `csv` under the header and not in the same row as header?

This is the results.
[image]

And down here is my coding.

```
import os

# ...

filename = 'C:/Desktop/GPS_Trial/Trial6/' + str(d1) + '_' + str(file_counter) +'.csv'
        
#check whether the file exist or not
rows_to_be_written = []
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    rows_to_be_written.append(header1)
    rows_to_be_written.append(header2)
    rows_to_be_written.append(header3)       
rows_to_be_written.append(gps)
rows_to_be_written.append(gps2)
rows_to_be_written.append(gps3)
                        
    #write the data into csv
with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(rows_to_be_written)
    print(gps, gps2, gps3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the headings separately, and only if they are not there already:

```
# check whether the file exist or not
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    headings = [header1, header2, header3]
else:
    headings = None
rows_to_be_written = [gps, gps2, gps3]

# write the data into csv
with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # Write headings if exist
    if headings != None:
        writer.writerow(headings)
    # Write rows
    writer.writerow(rows_to_be_written)
    print(gps, gps2, gps3)
```

I suggest you consider this approach

```
# Open file to see if there are headings
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    try:
        has_headings = csv.Sniffer().has_header(f.read(1024))
    except csv.Error:
        # The file seems to be empty
        has_headings = False


# Open to write. In append mode ("a")
with open(filename, "a") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    if has_headings:
        # Write the rows at the top
        writer.writerow(headings_list)
    # Use writerows if youe have a 2D list, else use a for loop of writer.writerow
    writer.writerows(lists_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

You write header with values in one row if it file not exists.
You should write it separately

```
    rows_to_be_written = []
    header = None
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        header = [header1, header2, header3]
    rows_to_be_written.append(gps)
    rows_to_be_written.append(gps2)
    rows_to_be_written.append(gps3)

    # write the data into csv
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        if header:
            writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(rows_to_be_written)
        print(gps, gps2, gps3)
```

Also may be you tried write rows, but you write only one row with header in it. Then change code like this

```
    rows_to_be_written = []
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        rows_to_be_written.append([header1, header2, header3])
    rows_to_be_written.append([gps, gps2, gps3])

    # write the data into csv
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='', encoding='UTF8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in rows_to_be_written:
            writer.writerow(row)
        print(gps, gps2, gps3)
```